# insert array into an array

Tags: java, android

In my android application i need to insert an array into an array and access its values.
Is there any way that i can get this done.

Please share your valuable suggestions
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what kind of arrays? are you using Collections like ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's the issue?

Give this a try:

```
ArrayList<ClassName> l1 = new ArrayList<ClassName> ();
```

Now suppose you have array objects `arr1` and `arr2`. You can add them to an ArrayList with the following:

```
l1.add(arr1);
l1.add(arr2);
```

Now you can access each element in `l1` with

```
for(int i=0; i < l1.size;i++){
    <ClassName>  obj = l1.get(i);
    // and do what you want to do 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically making a list of lists.  Create a new list then add that list to the master list.  Use generics so you don't have to do a lot of casting.

```
List<Object> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
listOfObjects.add(obj1);
listOfObjects.add(obj2);
List<List<Object>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
listOfLists.add(listOfObjects);

// get first object in first list
listOfLists.get(0).get(0);

// add to the first list
listOfLists.get(0).add(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a example, but for It is for C#

```
ArrayList MainArray = new ArrayList();

MainArray.Add(new ArrayList());
MainArray.Add(new ArrayList());
MainArray.Add(new ArrayList());

(MainArray[1] as ArrayList).Add("Hello");

Response.Write((MainArray[1] as ArrayList)[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String myArray[] = new int[10];
 
for(int i=0; i<myArray.length(); i++) {
    myArray[i] =value adding here;
}
```